# Bash IFS is ignoring the delimiter at the end of line

Tags: bash, shell, key-value, ifs

I have a file with full of key value pairs. I wrote this shell script which reads each line and split key value.

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
   something

done < < application.properties.
```

One of the property looks like this
`Connections/Database/Token=#!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw=`

As run my script, its splitting it okay but its ignoring the character `=` at the end of the line.

It gives

```
key = Connections/Database/Token
value = #!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw
```

but it should be giving like:

```
 key = Connections/Database/Token
 value = #!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw=
```

Comment: If your value also contains your delimiter, you can't use `IFS`.

Comment: I almost wonder if that should be considered a bug. `IFS== read -r key value <<< "name=abc=def"`, for example, would assign `abc=def` to `value`. I don't see any reason why a trailing `=` should be treated differently. (For what it's worth, `zsh` preserves the trailing `=`; `ksh` and `dash` do not.) I don't see anything in the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) that indicates a trailing delimiter should be discarded in this case.

Comment: In fact, `IFS== read -r key value <<< "name=abc=="` *does* preserve both `=` in the value of `value`.

Comment: Certainly seems like a conflict with the standard.  `If there are fewer vars than fields, the last var shall be set to a value comprising the following elements:  1) The field that corresponds to the last var in the normal assignment sequence described above, 2) The delimiter(s) that follow the field corresponding to the last var, 3) The remaining fields and their delimiters, with trailing IFS white space ignored`  In this case, there seem to be 2 vars and 3 fields (last field is empty), so item 2 indicates the delimiters that follow should be included.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, I'm not sure if there's something that indicates an empty *last* field is somehow treated differently (due to IFS whitespace or something).

Comment: This is interesting, 
I noticed there few other properties which is ending like `==`, and then it returned correctly.

Meaning, when the property looks like `Connections/IRIS_Database/Password=#!VWdg5neXrFiIbM30HoAzOwmH+f3Ko2FNtk6mPLhgOHw==`

it has returned the value correctly as `#!VWdg5neXrFiIbM30HoAzOwmH+f3Ko2FNtk6mPLhgOHw==`

Comment: I filed a bug report regarding this; I'll update with Chet's opinion.

Comment: Verdict: not a bug, just a weird quirk of POSIX (that `zsh` is alone in not conforming to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Add an explicit `=` to the end of each input line, then remove it from the resulting value before using it.

---

## Why it works the way it does

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf47. In short, the `=` in IFS is not treated as a field *separator*, but a field *terminator*, according to the [POSIX definition of field-splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).

When you write

```
IFS== read -r key value <<< "foo=var="
```

the input is first split into *two* fields, "foo" and "var" (not "foo", "var", and ""). There are exactly as many variables as fields, so you just get key=foo and value=var

If you have

```
IFS== read -r key value <<< "foo=var=="
```

now there *are* three fields: "foo", "var", and "". Because there are only two variables, then key=foo, and value is assigned:

1. the value "var", as normal
2. The delimiter "=" immediately after "var" in the input
3. The field "" from the input
4. The delimiter "=" following the "" in the input

See the [POSIX specification for `read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) for details about each variable to `read` is assigned a value after the input undergoes field-splitting.

So, there is never a trailing null field that results from field-splitting the input,
only a trailing *delimiter* that gets added back to the final variable.

---

## How to preserve the input

To work around this, add an explicit = to your input, and then remove it from the resulting value.

```
$ for input in "foo=bar" "foo=bar=" "foo=bar=="; do
> IFS== read -r name value <<< "$input="
> echo "${value%=}"
> done
bar
bar=
bar==
```

In your case, this means using something

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
   value=${value%=}
   ...    
done < < (sed 's/$/=/' application.properties)
```

Or, as suggested [first by Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59962739/1126841), use parameter expansion operators to split the input instead of let `read` do it.

```
while read -r input; do
    key=${input%%=*}
    value=${input#*=}
    ...
done < application.properties
```

Either way, though, keep in mind that *only* `=` is considered as the delimiter here; you many need to trim trailing whitespace from the key and leading whitespace from the value if your properties look like `name = value` rather than `name=value`.

Answer (score 1):

IFS method is definitely not good here. Try this instead.

```
while read -r item
do
    key="${item%%=*}"
    val="${item#*=}"
    echo "key = $key"
    echo "value = $val"
done < file
```

Well maybe IFS can work too like so

```
cat -E file | while IFS== read -r key value
do
    echo "key = $key"
    echo "value = ${value%$}"
done
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Used this test file

```
$ cat file
Connections/Database/Token=#!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw1=
Conn/Database/Token=#!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw2
Connections/Data/Token=#!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw3=
Connection/Data/Token=#!VWdg5neXrFiIbMxtAzOwmH+fM2FNtk6QPLhgOHw3=test
```

And i've used this commands to see what is going on

```
cat -E file | while IFS== read -r key value last; do echo "key = $key"; echo "value = $value"; echo "last = ${last-empty}"; done
cat -E file | while IFS== read -r key value;      do echo "key = $key"; echo "value = $value"; echo "last = ${last-empty}"; done
cat    file | while IFS== read -r key value last; do echo "key = $key"; echo "value = $value"; echo "last = ${last-empty}"; done
cat    file | while IFS== read -r key value;      do echo "key = $key"; echo "value = $value"; echo "last = ${last-empty}"; done
```

Comment: Both didn't work for me. Infact the first approach is not returning any values at all.